# MobX and hashmap update not triggering autorun

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm trying to update the _users hashmap of class Test, and two "strange" things are happening (I'm a MobX newbie):

1. MobX, even if strict mode is enabled, allows me to update _users even though it is observable and addUser() is not an @action
2. The autorun is being executed only once, while I expect it to be run three times

If I put `this._users = {}` inside `addUser()` things works as expected: MobX tells me to defined addUser as an action and the autorun is triggered multiple times. But this was for testing only, I don't need to reset the hashmap every time

How should I update _users to let MobX trigger events?

Code follows

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });


class Test {
    @observable _users = {};
    userCount = 0;

    addUser() {
        this._users[this.userCount++] = 0;
    }

}

var t = new Test();

autorun(function test () {
    console.log("users: ", t._users);
});

t.addUser();
t.addUser();
t.addUser();

console.log("users: ", (Object.keys(t._users)).length); // print users: 3
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `@observable.deep _users = {};` It should observe when you're dealing with an object. (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/api.html#decorators). Another possibility would be using `observable.map` (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html)

Comment: @observable.deep doesn't work, I'll give a look at observable map thank you

Answer (score 0):

For autorun to work (and observers in general), you have to access a property of the observed object. Only that reading (dereferencing) will tell mobx what to observe. You are not doing this in your autorun function, so autorun has no chance to get when it should run autorun again.

So in your case you have to read at least one prop of the observed object. So I would recommend to do the following:

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });


class Test {
    @observable _userStore = { users: {} };
    userCount = 0;

    addUser() {
        this._userStore.users[this.userCount++] = 0;
    }

}

var t = new Test();

autorun(function test () {
    console.log("users: ", t._userStore.users); // Here we are reading a prop of userStore
});

t.addUser();
t.addUser();
t.addUser();

console.log("users: ", (Object.keys(t._userStore.users)).length); // print users: 3
```

**References:**

- https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html